# Do multiple healing effects stack?

Tags: overwatch

If a player is receiving two instances of the same healing effect, like Lucio's aura, Mercy's beam, Soldier: 76's zone, or Zenyatta's orb, do they stack?

What if a team had six Lucios standing in a point? Would they all be getting 6x healing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Lucio's aura

Does not stack. You can have both speed boost and healing songs at the same time though, and Amp it Up can be staggered by different Lucio to provided the stronger heal for longer period of times.

> Mercy's beam

Yep, stacks.

> Soldier: 76's zone

Does not stack. Again, it's better to stagger them to provide a longer lasting Biotic Field.

> Zenyatta's orb

[Does not stack](http://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20742695178).

Any two different kinds of healing stack, and basically only Mercy's Caduceus staff stacks with itself, healing-wise.

I tested the Lucio, Mercy, and Soldier: 76 interactions myself during normal play. Also helps that my own observations and the Wiki's do not conflict with each other.

Comment: Both answers were submitted at about the same time, and both agree. I'm accepting this one because I like the way it directly addresses each specific heal and the way it is formatted.

Comment: http://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20742695178

Orb of Harmony does not stack with other Orbs of Harmony

Comment: Seems like this wasn't undone in later patches, I'll edit my post.

Comment: Wait, does Zenyatta's stack or not? Talking about edits in the post is confusing. We can see the edit history under the post. Just write what you currently mean, and leave any mention of edits out of it.